# Why can't I get Exchange 2003 to receive mail but can send mail?

Tags: exchange-2003, email

I have Exchange 2000 running on Win2k sp4 everything running fine.  I have a new machine with Win 2003 sp2 I have installed Exchange 2003 everything seems good. I see mail going out but I can't receive mail in through this server.  I am wanting to retire the 2000 machine. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Is your MX record pointed to the "new" box?

(I feel dirty for calling a Server 2003/Exchange 2003 box new)

Answer (score 0):

Under what circumstances are you seeing this problem? Are you having problems all the time, or only when you power-off or disconnect the old server computer?

Chris S's statement about your MX record nonwithstanding, I'm guessing that your "new" machine is behind a network-address translating firewall on your LAN. Is the firewall setup to forward incoming SMTP to the new machine? (Your old Exchange Server computer, if it is still receiving incoming email, should be receiving the mail and delivering it to the new machine anyway, but if you're disconnecting or powering-off the old server that won't happen.)

Comment: That was it.  My router was pointing to the old server.  Thanks.